# Normal time loading of page

Tags: php, load, blogs

I have blog and i would like to know is it normal time loading of page.

Time of loading is 0.104528188705 sec.
This time is without time for Internet connection.

Comment: "This time is without time"... mm, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.105 seconds is 105 milliseconds ; that seems quite no bad, actually, if you have several dynamic informations on your blog -- which means several SQL queries.

Of course, I suppose this is when there is virtually no load on your webserver ? If so, and you plan on having a lot of visits on your website, you might want to think a bit about some caching mecanisms.

Hint : to test with more *(virtual)* users and simulate a higher load, you might want to take a look at tools such as :

- [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)
- [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/)
- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

As a sidenote : remember that the time it takes to generate the page on the server is only a small portion of the time your users have to wait -- don't forget you can also optimize loading time, by grouping CSS/JS, using optimized images, leveraging HTTP caching, ...

For more informations on that subject, take a look at :

- [Web Performance Best Practices](https://code.google.com/intl/fr/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) *(google)*
- [Exceptional Performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/) *(yahoo)*

Comment: "Normal" is pretty hard to define, there : it all depends on what amount of informations you want to display ;-) *(and, of course, if you have compression enabled !)* ; if that un-compressed HTML, it doesn't feel too much.

Answer (score 0):

First, put your blog online if it's not already online.  There are many tools/extensions/web apps out there for website speed check/optimization. Here's one of them:  http://www.selfseo.com/website_speed_test.php